# Buzzing noise when accelerating from stop

Tags: noise, nissan

My Nissan Serena C25 makes a buzzing noise when accelerating from stop, but accelerates smoothly if the car is moving at roughly 50 Km/h and above. If the car is in Park and you press on the pedal it doesn’t make the noise. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you have the radio on?

Comment: The noise is there whether the radio is on or off.

Comment: Possible exhaust heatshield or broken pieces inside the converter?  Try tapping the exhaust with something like a rubber mallet to see if you can hear a similar buzz sound.

Comment: My buzzing noise was the left front wheel hub assembly